# finding the server spec. on which my website runs

Tags: asp.net, webserver, processor

i need to find out what are the details of the processor the server has. i need to know which kind of processor, type of OS, RAM etc. i've got a reply from one webhosting company: "This is a shared hosting server, it is a dual processor (quad core xeon 2.8) 16Gb ram, mirrored 300GB SAS15k drives"

how can i get those details on other servers without the webhosting company telling me?

thanks, yishai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need SSH access. If it's paid hosting, then most probably they will give you SSH access. From there, you can input these commands:

OS: `uname -arv`

CPU: `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

MEMORY: `cat /proc/meminfo`

HDD: `df`

Take NOTE that this only works for UNIX type OS.

**EDIT: For ASP.NET**

Just like phpinfo(); in PHP.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
   @ServerInfo.GetHtml()
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Almost all of this information can be gotten at without SSH access from most servers that allow you to run arbitrary scripts in any sufficiently powerful language.

Comment: thanks for the answer, sorry, it was a very good answer until i reached the last sentence :), i am using asp.net (time to edit the tags) is there a possible way to do so with asp.net? thanks

Comment: hi wooble, which script do i need to run to get this information? how can i use the script in my website? thanks

Comment: create a new file in your web root directory, and open it in your browser.

Comment: hi, i've created a file in the root dir called spec.htm and enter the content you offered but i only get the code in my browser and it doesn't run it.